# Unable to fetch playlists using spotify API custom hook, returning empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch playlist data using Spotify API, I've implemented a custom hook to get the spotifyAPI.

here I'm using the useEffect hook to fetch the playlist.

```
const spotifyApi: SpotifyWebApi = useSpotify();
const { data: session, status } = useSession();
const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState<Array<{ name: string }>>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(spotifyApi.getAccessToken()) {
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists().then(({data}: any) => {
      setPlaylists(data.body.items);
    })
  }
}, [session, spotifyApi]);

console.log(playlists);
```

here's how I'm implemented the useSpotify custom hook.

```
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import spotifyApi from "@/lib/spotify";

function useSpotify() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      //If refresh token attempt failed, redirect to sign in page
      if ((session as any).error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") {
        // refresh token
        signIn();
      }

      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(
        (session.user as { accessToken: string }).accessToken
      );
    }
  }, [session]);

  return spotifyApi;
}

export default useSpotify;
```

the hook is returning an empty array instead of the array of the playlists

[image: error image]

you can look at the full repo here: https://github.com/dipesh2508/Vibes

Comment: I assume the `spotifyApi` in your useEffect dependency array is not triggering a re-render so `spotifyApi.getAccessToken()` will always return false? What happens if you do a console.log inside the `if(spotifyApi.getAccessToken()) {`? does it reach this point

Comment: After running your code, the accessToken you are tying to set at `spotifyApi.setAccessToken((session as any)?.accessToken);` does not actually contain an accessToken.